# Vim key remaping doesn't work in chaining commands

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin, ideavim

I have following vimrc file

```
map u <Up>
map n <Left>
map e <Down>
map i <Right>
noremap h i
noremap t w
noremap s b
```

Delete or changing word with `dt` or `ct` works, but when I want to delete inner word with `dht` or `cht` it doesn't work but `dhw` or `chw` works. Am I missing something in this remaping of the keys?

I have tried with map instead noreamp but it didn't worked.

Comment: "Am I missing something in this remaping of the keys?" Yes, you are missing a bunch of things: first, they are not "remappings", second, they are overriding pretty useful commands, third, they are pointless because the location of the corresponding key was irrelevant when defining original one-letter commands, it is their meaning that matters.

Comment: I simpy want to remap keys to more ergonomic places on my split keyboard. I know about motivation about every key assigment but don't care I want keys that I use the most to be under my fingers. Just wanted eg. for t to behave as w in original vim setup.

Comment: this is a really really bad idea... are you aware of what commands you are overwriting? `(u)ndo` `(n)ext match`, `(e)nd of word`, `(i)nsert mode`... I mean you will have to switch all of them. Vim is already home-row optimized. If you are using another layout like dvorak there are specialised articles about that. If it is the default layout your keyboard sucks if you can't reach de keys. If you really want to go ahead you should got to `:h mapping`

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but I have switched to colemak and bouth ergo keyboard bcs of wrist pain. Now some of characts I used a lot are not in best position. I hope that this key remaping will help me alleviate my RSI.

Answer (score 0):

Vim's operator-pending mode is likely not expecting two consecutive mappings of individual characters.  However you can do a multi-character mapping.

```
noremap ht iw
noremap at aw
```

This will let you do `dht`, `dat`, `cht`, and `cat`, as well as `vht` and `vat`.

For multi-character maps, please be aware of the `'timeoutlen'` option setting.  This is normally defaulted to 1000ms.  If you have a mapping for both `h` and for `ht`, then this will slow down your `h` mapping because Vim must wait up to 1000ms for you to possibly type `t`.   You can reduce `'timeoutlen'` to a shorter time but it must still be long enough to let you type both `h` and `t`.

The `noremap` command applies to Normal, Visual and Operator-Pending modes.
You probably want to specify only Operator-Pending and Visual modes and exclude Normal mode so that you don't slow down your other Normal mode mappings.

```
onoremap ht iw
onoremap at aw
vnoremap ht iw
vnoremap at aw
```